# PHP Times Table creation

Tags: php

Hi I'm trying to figure out some code in PHP, I've been given the task to make a basic times table input, I have that part figured out. I have also to reverse the order the table is being output. So instead of the example running from 1 x 10=10 down I have to reverse that order from 10 x 10=100 down instead. This part I can't figure out.[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0r1s.jpg)

```
if (isset($_POST['calculate'])) {

$start = $_POST['startNumber'];
$end = $_POST['endNumber'];
$times = $_POST['times'];

for($start; $start <= $end; $start++) {

    $answer = $start * $times;
    echo $start, " x ", $times, " = ", $answer, "<BR>";
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by reversing the output? What's the desired result?

Comment: Do you mean you want to iterate from the end, like this: `for($end; $end >= $start; $end--) {` ?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. So instead of the example running from 1 x 10=10 down I have to reverse that order from 10 x 10=100 down instead.

Comment: W̶h̶a̶t̶'̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶d̶i̶f̶f̶e̶r̶e̶n̶c̶e̶ ̶b̶e̶t̶w̶e̶e̶n̶ ̶`̶e̶n̶d̶N̶u̶m̶b̶e̶r̶`̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶`̶t̶i̶m̶e̶s̶`̶?̶ ̶W̶h̶y̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶j̶u̶s̶t̶ ̶p̶o̶s̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶t̶a̶r̶t̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶e̶n̶d̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶n̶u̶m̶b̶e̶r̶s̶?̶ Nevermind, I see it now.

Comment: @waterloomatt looking at the code it would be the a1...aX (`$start`...`$end`), with `$times` being the multiplier. So for the '2 times' table, the value would be 2.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could tweak your original code, but rather than output it straight away add it to the current output at the start.  The output the result at the end

```
if (isset($_POST['calculate'])) {

    $start = $_POST['startNumber'];
    $end = $_POST['endNumber'];
    $times = $_POST['times'];

    $output = '';
    for($start; $start <= $end; $start++) {
        $answer = $start * $times;
        $output =  $start . " x " . $times ." = " . $answer . "<BR>" . $output;
    }
    
    echo $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just push to an array instead, reverse the array after the loop, join the array into a string, then echo the output.

Also be careful with user submitting input. In this case I believe you're expecting ints so I typecasted them for you.

```
if (isset($_POST['calculate'])) {

    $start = (int)$_POST['startNumber'];
    $end = (int)$_POST['endNumber'];
    $times = (int)$_POST['times'];

    $out = [];
    for(; $start <= $end; $start++) {
        $answer = $start * $times;
        $out[] =  "$start x $times = $answer<br>";
    }

    $out = array_reverse($out);
    echo implode('',$out);
}
```

Alternatively, you can just walk the loop in reverse:

```
if (isset($_POST['calculate'])) {

    $start = (int)$_POST['startNumber'];
    $end = (int)$_POST['endNumber'];
    $times = (int)$_POST['times'];

    for(; $end >= $start; $end--) {
        $answer = $end * $times;
        echo "$end x $times = $answer<br>";
    }
}
```

A cleaner looking loop would probably involve [range](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php):

```
if (isset($_POST['calculate'])) {

    $start = (int)$_POST['startNumber'];
    $end = (int)$_POST['endNumber'];
    $times = (int)$_POST['times'];

    foreach(range($end, $start) as $i) {
        echo "$i x $times = ". ($i * $times) ."<br>\n";
    }
}
```

You can also add in [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) if you'd like:

```
if (isset($_POST['calculate'])) {

    $start = (int)$_POST['startNumber'];
    $end = (int)$_POST['endNumber'];
    $times = (int)$_POST['times'];

    array_map(function($i) use ($times){
        echo "$i x $times = ". ($i * $times) ."<br>\n";
    }, range($end, $start));
}
```

Or you can just avoid all of this and just reverse your $start and $end parameters.

So instead of this:

```
$start = $_POST['startNumber'];
$end = $_POST['endNumber'];
```

Use this:

```
$end = $_POST['startNumber'];
$start = $_POST['endNumber'];
```

But kindly also handle user submitted data with care, otherwise echoing it directly allows them to inject HTML onto the page and do things like run JavaScript. Best to typecast it to int or float in your case as the code expects it to be such. Putting `(int)` in front will [typecast](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) it. You could also use (float) or (double) etc. You can also do stuff like running it through a mathematical operation first like multiplying by 1 etc. In other situations where you're not working on numbers, but rather strings, you'd generally reach for [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) before outputting a string like the input the user submitted back to the html so it's properly escaped to display as text within the html rather than allow them to utilize html and/or run javascript etc.

Thus instead of:

```
$start = $_POST['startNumber'];
$end = $_POST['endNumber'];
```

You'd have:

```
$end = (int)$_POST['startNumber'];
$start = (int)$_POST['endNumber'];
```

or:

```
$end = (float)$_POST['startNumber'];
$start = (float)$_POST['endNumber'];
```

or

```
$end = $_POST['startNumber'] * 1;
$start = $_POST['endNumber'] * 1;
```

Etc.

If I had to choose personally, I'd reach for range.

Comment: In your second example, you want to use `$end` instead of `$start` in the for loop. Ex, http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ded90107a1daea3c35ba681bae66a7248174abda

Comment: @waterloomatt fixed

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way I can think of is to create an array with `range` starting with the end value. With that, you can simply iterate over the numbers and do your calculations.

Demo, http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/727cb873fa8d5567157bfcd03f4bde5f4a574a4d

```
<?php

$start = 1;
$end = 10;
$multiplier = 10;

$reversed = range($end, $start);

foreach ($reversed as $input) {
    echo sprintf('%s x %s = %s %s', $input, $multiplier, $input * $multiplier, "\n");
}
```

Comment: Why are you using array_reverse? Why not `range($end, $start)`?

Comment: Because I didn't think of that :) Thanks for pointing it out. Updated.